# Find the lower bound of the maximal 1x1 square in a 2x2 square

Tags: geometry

My problem description is a little bit long, I'll try to state it clearly.

Assume that we have a 2x2 square, namely $R$, containing many points, each of which has a positive weight. Let $r_{max}$ be the 1x1 square that is inside $R$ with each side is parallel to that of R, and covers points with largest total weights. It is easy to show that the ratio $|r_{max}|/|R| \ge 1/4$, where $|r|$ and $|R|$ are total weights in $r$ and $R$, respectively.

My problem is slightly different. In addition to points, we now have edges between some pairs of points, and edges also have weights. And every edge can be covered by at least one 1x1 square (i.e. there is always an 1x1 square that can cover this edge). Weight of a 1x1 square now is the sum of weights of points inside it plus sum of weights of edges inside it, i.e. edges with both ending points also in the 1x1 square. Again, call $r_{max}$ is the 1x1 square with maximum weights (point weights + edge weights). *What is the lower bound of the ratio $|r_{max}|/|R|$ in this case?*

I can prove that if there is no constrain on edge weights, i.e. edge weights can be arbitrarily large, there is no lower bound (in other words, the ratio can be arbitrarily small). So I have one condition on edge weights that the weight of an edge can not be larger than sum of weights of its two points. That means that $e_{ij} \le w_i + w_j$, where $e_{ij}$, $w_i$ and  $w_j$ are weights of edges connecting points $i$ and $j$, and weights of points $i$ and $j$, respectively. So, the final question is, *in the case we have constrains on edge weights described above, do we have bound of the ratio $|r_{max}|/|R|$? If yes, what is it?*

Hope that my problem is well described. Any suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: Can multiple edges have the same endpoint? If so, then the best lower bound is 0. If not, then it would be 1/8. The reason being that the edges could be all too long to fit in 1x1 square.

Comment: @PaulSinclair: Yes, multiple edges can have same endpoint. I forgot to add one more condition: every edge can be cover by at least one 1x1 square. I'll edit the post. Thanks.

Comment: @PaulSinclair: btw, how do you come up with the answer of 1/8 in the second case?

Comment: The edge weight condition and single use endpoints would mean that at least 1/2 the weight is in the points. Even if you pick up no edges, you can still get at least 1/4 of the point weight, thus 1/8 of the total.

Comment: And for the first case (without the edge length limit), you could put $N$ pts on each of two lines greater than $\sqrt 2$ apart and connect all pairs of points from opposite lines, with all pts weighing the same and all edges weighing as much as 2 points. The best that can be contained is $N$ points, leaving a weight ratio of $\frac 1 {2(N+1)}$. By choosing large enough $N$, you can make it as small as you like. But with the length restriction, this is no longer possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have the answer for this problem. I found an example showing that we do not have lower bound in the case of constrained edges.

From the square R, in the lower left corner square, we create N points, namely $D_1$,$D_2$,...$D_N$. Those points are located in the 1/4 arc of the circle with center at the center of R. From each point $D_i$, we create two points, $E_i$ and $F_i$, so that $E_i$ and $F_i$ are located in 2 corner points of a square r with $D_i$ is the lower left point (see figure).

[image: Fig.1]

Then, in the edge $\overline{E_iF_i}$ we create N points and link them to $D_i$. Let weights of  $D_i$ and newly created be 1. And points created in the edge $\overline{E_iF_i}$ above have 0 weight (or very small weight). We can easily proof that the squares that have $D_i$ in the lower left corner are $r_{max}$, and have the weight of N+1. Because R's weight is $N^2$, then lower bound of ratio $|r_{max}|/|R|$ is 0.

[image: Fig.2]

Answer (score 1):

Even with your additional conditions, the best lower bound is $0$.

(**Edited** to simplify example) Consider a circular arc of radius $\sqrt 2$, short enough to fit inside a 1x1 square. Place $2N$ points on the arc, and $1$ point at the center. Connect each point on the arc to the center with an edge. Each point on the arc has weight $1$, while the center has weight $N - 1$. Each edge has weight $N$. So the total weight is $$2N\times 1 + 1 \times (N - 1) + 2N\times N = 2N^2 + 3N - 1$$

If we include the center inside the 1x1 square, the only way to include anything else is the put the center at one corner and one of the arc points at the opposite corner. Then we also pick up the edge between them, but no other points or edges. So the weight is $N - 1 + 1 + N = 2N$. If we do not include the center, we cannot include any of the edges either, but all of the other points can be included, also producing a weight of $2N$. So the maximum ratio we can produce is $$\frac {2N}{2N^2 + 3N - 1}$$

The limit as $N \to \infty$ is $0$, so no lower bound above $0$ is possible.

Comment: In this case, not all edges can be covered by an 1x1 square. Only edges that create an $45^o$ with horizontal line can be in one 1x1 square, others cannot be.

Comment: You never said that the 1x1 square had to have sides parallel to the 2x2. I assumed that any 1x1 square was okay. The parallel restriction isn't going to save it. It just means that a different shape is needed for the arc than a circle.

Comment: I'll have to retract that last comment. The parallel sides restriction does appear to prevent this particular approach. I still can't say for sure that some other variant will not force a lower bound of $0$, but a common endpoint to all edges does not appear to work. The general idea is to create a situation where the number of edges can be increased without limit, but only a fixed maximum can be put in any 1x1 square. If that can be arranged, the only lower bound is $0$.

Comment: @ Paul: I understand your approach. I tried many ways but not successfully. So I think we have a bound in this case.

Comment: I have a  strong belief that the bound is 1/16. To have this, firstly I randomly create N points in one 1x1 corner square, then duplicate them into 3 other squares. So for every point, there are 3 duplicated points in other corner squares. Among these 4 points, I create 6 edges connecting all of them. We can easily see that every 1x1 square in the  2x2 one covers the same number of N points, and 6 edges...

Comment: ... If point weights are 1 and edge weights are 2, an 1x1 square has a score of (4N + 12). Because score of R is 4N + 6*2*N = 16N, then r_max/R = (N+12)/16N. When $N \rightarrow \infty$, the ratio goes to 1/16. However, I cannot prove that this is worst situation we can achieve.